# Is there any way to support secured connections by using "SocketActivityTriger"?

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, win-universal-app

While developing UWP application I recently have a strange issue with establishing SSL/TLS connection.

I use StreamSocket to establish SSL/TLS connection and work fine.

```
socket.EnableTransferOwnership(TaskId,SocketActivityConnectedStandbyAction.Wake);
await socket.ConnectAsync(hostName, port, SocketProtectionLevel.Tls12);
```

After I transfer the socket ownership to the "SocketActivityTrigger," I found the data I recieve from the SocketActivity were wrong.

```
await socket.CancelIOAsync();
socket.TransferOwnership(socketId);
```

But if I just use plain socket to establish connection, all thing work fine.

Is this a known problem? Because I can't find any solution in the develop guidelines. Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I have the same problem. A asked questions here - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07b90540-ed8b-488e-9bba-04d844f0b1d9/uwp-streamsocket-in-background-unknown-encoding?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: So...did you find any solution?